# Vagrant ssh and private network broken

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, vagrant

Server is a fresh centos72 install, with pretty much dead in the water vagrant/vbox provider installed.

I have vagrant `1.8.6` rpm installed on a server with `vbox 5.1.8r111374`
, the box `boxcutter/centos72` comes up, with error:

```
SSH auth method: private key
    gocd: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
```

And yet... `vagrant ssh` works. The config file is basic af.

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
 config.vm.define "boxname" do |boxname|
     boxname.vm.box = "boxcutter/centos72"
     boxname.vm.hostname = "test"
     boxname.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.111.10"
     boxname.vm.provision :shell,
         path: "prov.sh"
 end
end
```

This can't run the prov script as it never gets past ssh set up. And `vagrant provision` won't work either because of the error above. I've obviously specified a private network, however once on the box the ifcfg-enp file looks like this:

```
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
```

And the IP is a 10 address.

Answer (score 1):

VirtualBox 5.1.x seems to be having major issues. Revert to 5.0.26 (5.0.28 seems to have major networking issues, too).

Comment: We, too, had problems on Virtualbox 5.1.8 with our Vagrant setup — FWIW, we were able to make things work with 5.1.6.

Comment: same issue on 5.0.26